# 0 vs None: 0 should still be inside my if-call

Tags: python, django

I write in my template: `{% if ticket_price.discounted_price %}`. Now that works perfect, until ticket_price.discounted_price = 0. As 0 can happen (original price = 10, discount = 10 > discounted_price = 0) if want to include this option.

However, it seems `if ticket_price.discounted_price` 'thinks' 0 is equal to None. How would you solve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can check explicitly for None `{% if ticket_price.discounted_price is None %}` see this post for more details [not None test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python)

Comment: That's perfect `{% if ticket_price.discounted_price is not None %}`solved it!

Answer (score 1):

"if" tests for truthiness in Python. If you want to explicitly check for None:

`{% if ticket_price.discounted_price == None %}`

See also: [What is the equivalent of "none" in django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945321/what-is-the-equivalent-of-none-in-django-templates)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the help. `{% if ticket_price.discounted_price is not None %}` was the solution.